# Logarithmic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

> Consider the following sequence: $μ_{n + 1} = \log_2 (n + 1 + μ_n)$ for $n ≥ 0$ with $μ_0 = 1$. Show by mathematical induction that $μ_{n + 1} ≥ μ_n$ for any $n ∈ N$. You can use the fact that the function $\log_2 (x)$ is always increasing when $x ≥ 1$ (ie, if $x ≥ y ≥ 1$ then $\log_2 x ≥ \log_2 y$).

Can I get help with this, please?

I can solve this for the base case ($μ_1≥μ_0$) but not beyond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\mu_{n+1} = \log_2(n + 1 + \mu_n)$ for $n \ge 0$ and $\mu_0 = 1$

Base Case: Simply, for $n=0$ we have $\mu_1 = \log_2(0 + 1 + \mu_0) = \log_2(2) = 1 \ge \mu_0$

Now assume $\mu_{n+1} = \log_2(n + 1 + \mu_n) \implies \mu_{n+1}\ge \mu_n$ is true for $n=m$. We will show that it works for $n=m+1$

We have, $\mu_{m+1} = \log_2(m + 1 + \mu_m) \ge \log_2(m + 1+\mu_{m-1})$ By the monotonicity of logarithms and our inductive hypothesis. Finally $\mu_{m+1} \ge \log_2(m + 1+\mu_{m-1}) \ge \log_2(m +\mu_m-1) = \mu_m$ for all $n=m\in N$

Comment: hey thanks for your help , i am a bit late on that.. taught i thanked you already :)